# Adding Splunk logback appender prevents application termination

Tags: logback, splunk

I have the following logback configuration and I am using it in a very simple Java application that does nothing except logging one line. When I uncomment the Splunk appender line it doesn't let the application exit, even though the application is finished.

Is there a way to terminate all the logging threads so that the main application exits?

logback.xml

```
<appender name="SPLUNK" class="com.splunk.logging.HttpEventCollectorLogbackAppender">
    <url>${splunkUrl}</url>
    <token>${splunkToken}</token>
    <source>${projectName}</source>
    <host>${COMPUTERNAME}</host>
    <sourcetype>batch_application_log:json</sourcetype>
    <disableCertificateValidation>true</disableCertificateValidation>
    <!--<messageFormat>json</messageFormat>-->
    <!--<retries_on_error>1</retries_on_error>-->
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <pattern>"%msg"</pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>
<root level="INFO">
     <!--<appender-ref ref="SPLUNK"/>--> if I uncomment this line application never exits
</root>
```

Java code

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);
    logger.info("******");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could add a Logback [shutdown hook](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#stopContext), this will close all appenders and stop any active threads related to Logback.

For example:

```
<configuration debug="true">
    <shutdownHook class="ch.qos.logback.core.hook.DelayingShutdownHook">
        <!-- 
            the default value is 0 millis, I have included a non default
            value here just to show you how it can be supplied 
        -->
        <delay>10</delay>
    </shutdownHook>

    ... 
<configuration>
```

With the shutdown hook in place and `debug="true"` Logback will emit its own log events like so ...

```
08:57:19,410 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.hook.DelayingShutdownHook@2bafec4c - Sleeping for 10 milliseconds
08:57:19,421 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.hook.DelayingShutdownHook@2bafec4c - Logback context being closed via shutdown hook
```

Note: there is no requirement to use `debug="true"`, I have only o
included that to show you how to verify that the shutdown hook has been executed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, shutdown hook has no impact in this case as it never gets called. I tried your configuration and still the same.